# Radon-Nikodym derivative of SDE law

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $(\Omega, (\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space, $T$ some index set, and $(S, \Sigma)$ a measurable space. Let $X^f$ and $X^g : T × \Omega \to S$ be stochastic processes defined by the stochastic differential equations
Let $$dX^{f}_t = f(X_t) dt + \sigma(X_t)dW_t, \\ dX^{g}_t = g(X_t) dt + \sigma(X_t)dW_t.$$
Denote by $\mathbb Q_f$, resp. $\mathbb Q_g$, the corresponding laws, i.e.,
$$\mathbb Q_f[A] = \mathbb P[\{\omega: t\mapsto X_t^f(\omega) \in A \}] $$

I want to compute the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac {d\mathbb Q_f}{ d \mathbb Q_g}$.

I know that the answer is connected to Girsanov's theorem, which needs to be applied twice.

> **Girsanov's Theorem** Let $\theta_t$ be an adapted process satiysfying the Novikov condition. Define a probability measure $\mathbb Q$ by $\frac{d\mathbb Q}{d\mathbb P}\Big|_{\mathcal F_t} = \mathcal E(\theta_t)$. Then the stochastic process $t \mapsto W_t - \int_0^t \theta_s ds$ is a standard Wiener process under the measure $\mathbb Q$.

---

**My (updated) attempt.**
As pointed out by @zhoraster, I should consider the process $Y_t = \Sigma^{-1}(X^f_t) X^f_t$, which satisfies
$$dY^f_t = \sigma^{-1}(X_t) f(X_t) dt + dW_t\enspace,$$
i.e. $Y:t\mapsto \int_0^t \sigma^{-1}(X_s) f(X_s) ds + W_t$.

According to Girsanov's theorem, this is a standard Wiener process under $\mathbb Q$, defined by $\frac{d\mathbb Q}{d\mathbb P} = \mathcal E\left(-\sigma^{-1}(X_t) f(X_t)\right)$, i.e., with $\theta_t = -\sigma^{-1}(X_t) f(X_t)$.
Further, $Y_t^0$ is a standard Wiener process wrt to $\mathbb Q$.

Define
$$\Phi: \Omega \to C([0,T],S)\\
\omega \mapsto \left(t\mapsto W_t(\omega)\right) \enspace.$$

We know (**?**) that the laws $\mathbb Q_{Y_t^f}$ and $\mathbb Q_{Y_t^0}$ satisfies for all measurable $A \subset C(T,S)$ that
$$
\mathbb Q_{Y_t^0}[A] 
= \mathbb P[\{\omega: t\mapsto W_t(\omega) \in A \}]
= \mathbb P[\Phi^{-1}(A)]
= (\Phi_* \mathbb P) [A]
\\
\mathbb Q_{Y_t^f}[A] 
= \mathbb Q[\{\omega: t\mapsto W_t(\omega) \in A \}]
= \mathbb Q[\Phi^{-1}(A)]
= (\Phi_* \mathbb Q) [A]
$$

By the definition of $\mathbb Q$, this means that
$$\mathbb Q_{Y_t^f}\big[A\big] 
= \mathbb Q\left[\Phi^{-1}(A)\right]
= \mathbb E_{\mathbb P}\left[\mathcal E(\theta_t) \mathbb 1_{\Phi^{-1}(A)}\right]
 $$

In other words, $\mathbb Q_{Y_t^0} = \Phi_* \mathbb P$ and $\mathbb Q_{Y_t^f} = \Phi_* \mathbb Q$. If the former is true, then my question reduces to whether the Radon-Nikodym derivative of push forward measures is the same as the Radon-Nikodym derivative of the original measures. Presumably, this only holds if $\Phi$ satisfies certain properties.

**Update:** Bounty added

Comment: Girsanov's theorem has a few different formulations that are all equivalent. Can you specify what exactly you mean by Girsanov's theorem?

Comment: @AsbjørnHolk Yes, I should have included the theorem statement. Added it now. Thanks.

Comment: 1) you denote to different things by $\Sigma$ (sigma-algebra and the diffusion coefficient); 2) divide by $\Sigma$ (assuming it's not zero) to get the formulation of GT

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks for pointing this out. I made some progress, but still, I could not finish the proof.

Comment: I bet it would be easier to consider $\mathcal E \big((f(X)-g(X))/\sigma(X)\big)$ to go directly from $X_f$ to $X_g$.

Comment: @zhoraster but wouldn't I get stuck at the same point regardless?

Comment: Note that you just need to represent somehow $\mathbb{Q}(A) = \int_{A} F_t d\mathbb{P}$. Girsanov theorem allow you to make the same step for SDE satisfying processes.

Comment: @openspace I already know what $F_t$ is. This is exactly the statement of Girsanov's theorem in the question. What I don't know is, how the equation in your comment relates to the SDE laws $\mathbb Q_{Y^f_t}$.